# Sympy - print(limit()) as latex

Tags: python-3.x, latex, sympy

Probably this is a question easy to answer but I couldn't find any solution that worked for me. I want to have the content of `print()` to be displayed as latex.

Edit: I'm using jupyter.

```
import sympy
from sympy.assumptions import assuming, Q
sympy.init_printing()

K,L,alpha = sympy.symbols("K,L,alpha")
Y = (K**alpha)*(L**(1-alpha))

Y

with assuming(Q.is_true(L == 1)):
    print(sympy.limit(Y,K,1,"-"))

sympy.limit(1/alpha,L,0)
```

For the calculation without assumption (last code line) everything works fine.

I have already tried `latex(print())` but that only gave me latex code but no latex output.

Best,
Fabian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I used the following solution:

```
sympy.limit(Y.subs(L,1),K,1,"-")
```

Easy and works fine ...

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following. Insert at the beginning of the code

```
from IPython.display import display
```

and replace `print(...)` with `display(...)`, e.g.,

```
display(sympy.limit(Y,K,1,"-"))
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work for me. The result I get is `'L L^{- \\alpha}'`